# how to aggregation without group_by in mysql?

Tags: mysql

This is table.

| idx | statusIdx | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-05-12 02:24 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-05-12 02:24 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-06-12 02:24 |
| 4 | 1 | 2022-07-12 02:24 |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-07-12 02:24 |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-07-12 02:24 |

How can i get like this?

|  | stauts1 | status2 | status3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-06 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-07 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| sum | 3 | 2 | 1 |

I've tried to use `row_number()` and `count() over()`.

```sql
SELECT 
    FDATE, cnt1, cnt2, cnt3
FROM 
    (SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y.%m") AS FDATE, 
        COUNT(case when statusIdx=1 then 1 end) over(PARTITION BY date, statusIdx) AS cnt1,
        COUNT(case when statusIdx=2 then 1 end) over(PARTITION BY date, statusIdx) AS cnt2, 
        COUNT(case when statusIdx=3 then 1 end) over(PARTITION BY date, statusIdx) AS cnt3,
        row_number() over (PARTITION by date, statusIdx) AS rnk
    FROM transfer
    WHERE date betWEEN "20212-05-01" AND "2022-07-31"
    ORDER BY FDATE  ASC
    ) t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

It show vertically counting.

| num | FDATE | cnt1 | cnt2 | cnt3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-05 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-06 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-07 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2022-07 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

How to aggregation without group_by in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used sum() over partition. see  [dbfidde link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9086aca22ed5d9dbceb6846e6b0e891e)  if this works.